# Above line should be printed if the next line starts with a particular word

Tags: unix

How do I print a line which matches a particular pattern and the line before it?

I do have a dump like this:

```
Apple:Orange=9942501133;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501144;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501155;
Apple:Orange=9942501166;
Apple:Orange=9942501177;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501188;
Apple:Orange=9942501199;
Apple:Orange=9942501200;
Apple:Orange=9942501211;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501222;
```

The output result to be the above line of "Fault Code 9" with Fault Code 9 included:

```
Apple:Orange=9942501133;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501144;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501177;
Fault Code 9
Apple:Orange=9942501211;
Fault Code 9
```